# how to maintain percentage width with margins

Tags: html, css

I have a floated list that contains 3 boxes with the same height. I gave each of them width of 33.333% to get them equaled and to fill the whole container.

I have to get the middle box margined both sides with 5px and because of that my 33.333% gets more than 100%.

I know I can use calc(100% - 5px) and solve this, but the problem is that I don't want any margins for the outer boxes, just for the middle box. With that method I get 5px margin left for the left box.

```
.highlights-list {
width: 30%;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
border: 2px solid lime;
padding: 0;
}
.highlight {
    width: calc(33.333%- 5px);
    text-align: left;
    opacity: 0.9;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    list-style-type: none;
    background: red;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

You can see my whole fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ronilitman/13j4qqqe/).

Answer (score 4):

Much simpler with `flexbox`

```css
.wrap {
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: auto;
}
.box {
  height: 150px;
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.wrap > div:nth-child(2) {
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Also worth mentioning in your answer that `flexbox` actually has better browser support than `calc` (ignoring vendor prefixes) according to caniuse.com.

Comment: And using `box-sizing: border-box;` will give you better browser support than `flex` (according to caniuse.com)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is pretty simple - http://jsfiddle.net/13j4qqqe/3/

```
.highlight:nth-child(2) {
    width: calc(33.333%- 10px);
    margin: 0 5px;
}
```

Comment: In your fiddle the layout gets broken.

Comment: @Lucian what's your browser?

Comment: Opera 30.0. Not sure if it's a browser problem, the third element gets pushed under the first: http://prntscr.com/7zq8is

Comment: @Lucian here's a table of browsers that support this feature - http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc This is how it looks in Google Chrome  44.0.2403.125 - http://filepic.ru/file/1438462287.png - first is yours, second - mine

Comment: And as you can see Opera 30 supports `calc`. :)

Comment: @Lucian sorry, but Opera 30.0 is used by 0,43% of users, meanwhile IE 8 is used by almost 2% and it does not support `calc`. However, if somebody is looking for a cross-browser solution - I have one: http://jsfiddle.net/13j4qqqe/6/

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution will be to override the margin related settings for the 1st child:

```
.highlight:first-child {
    width: 33.333%;
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `box-sizing: border-box;` to `.highlight`, change `margin-left` to `margin: 2px;` and set `width: calc(33.333% - 4px);`

```
.highlight {
    width: calc(33.333% - 4px);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: left;
    opacity: 0.9;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    list-style-type: none;
    background: red;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/13j4qqqe/7/

Comment: In that way my :nth-child(2) gets less width than his siblings. Is there a way to maintain that too?

Comment: Yes. Just add `box-sizing: border-box;` to `.highlight`, change `margin-left` to `margin: 2px;` and set `width: calc(33.333% - 4px);`. This will do it, without using any pseudo-selectors. I edit my answer to reflect this.